# Где можно найти примеры использования RSpec в реальных приложениях?

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails

Я пишу приложение на RubyOnRails, понадобилось написать серию тестов. На [официальном сайте](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails) есть примеры, но их очень мало.

Где я могу найти исходный код какого-нибудь веб-проекта в котором активно используется test-framework RSpec?

RSpec >= 2.0.0

Rails >= 3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень много проектов на гитхабе(из числа известных) используют спеки - можно их посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

есть соц сеть diaspora и gitlab отличные примеры rails приложений.
все это можно найти на github

Answer (score 0):

Неплохой [туториал](http://russian.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning) по рельсам. А [вот](https://github.com/phil303/Michael-Hartl-Tutorial) исходники к этому тутору.

Там хорошо расписано про RSpec. Я советовал бы по учебникам учить, т.к. в реальных приложениях код тестов может быть довольно нетривиален, тоже самое что первокурснику давать в качестве примеров по Си исходники ядра линукса =)